# GROUP BY and subquery in Select

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

so the issue that I have is that I am not sure why the answer for this problem is no.

[image: Queries]

`Project(pid,name,startYear)
Developer(did,name,hireYear)
WorksOn(pid,did,year)`
 as the schema.

I understand that in Q7, it selects all x.did's along with the count that have year greater than 2010 and then groups by X.did.
For Q8, it should select the count of all x.did that have x.did and year > 2010 along with x.did.

I don't entirely understand why these queries are different, and I would appreciate any help understanding it!

Comment: I assume there might be many rows in WorksOn for each `did`. Q7 returns only one row per distinct `did`, by grouping them. But Q8 returns _all_ the rows of WorksOn.

Comment: The Q8 doesn't have the condition `Year > 2000` in outer `WHERE` clause, so the result will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first one only selects rows, where the year is larger than 2010. The second just retrieves all rows, no matter the year. The count will be 0 for all rows with a year less than or equal 2010. In the first the `GROUP BY` also has the effect, that in the result the `did` is unique. In the second one this isn't necessarily the case. If the `did` isn't unique in the table it's not unique in the result either.

Answer (score 2):

They are not similar at all.

- The second selects all rows in the table; the first only selects rows that match the `where` condition.
- The second selects all rows, even when there are duplicates on `X.did`.  The first only selects one row per `X.did`.
- The first will never return a second column with a zero value; the second will.

There are very narrow circumstances where the two return the same result set.  You should think about what data would make that possible.